# Oracle APEX display blob images directly in a report

Tags: image, blob, oracle-apex

I would like to know how one can display image type BLOBs uploaded as per this stack overflow question [Use of BLOB type column in Oracle APEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618590/use-of-blob-type-column-in-oracle-apex), as images in a classic or interactive report instead of the normal download links.

I noticed that you can change the blob column attribute's Content Disposition field to inline, which then allows you to click through to another page where the image is displayed; but I want the image to display directly in the report without having to click on it.

The inline image displayed in a new page has the following url

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_util.get_blob?s=34564408462&a=4794&c=16789110088070077&p=2&k1=21&k2=&ck=D4QFl4Z9txsufDbmUOmKeirK4&rt=CR

which suggests that one might be able to use apex_util.get_blob. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I would suggest installing the "Sample Database Application" from pre-packaged apps and see how it's done there for the product pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented same in classic report.

I followed this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_util.htm#AEAPI129
This may help you to resolve your doubts

Comment: I tried select "PERSON_ID", 
"FIRST_NAME",
"LAST_NAME",
dbms_lob.getlength("PHOTO") "PHOTO",
"MIME_TYPE",
"FILE_NAME",
"CHARACTER_SET",
"CHANGE_DATE",
APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC 
(
    p_item_name           => 'PHOTO',
    p_v1                  => to_char(PERSON_ID),
    p_v2                  => null,
    p_content_disposition => 'inline'
)   EMPLOYEE_PHOTO
from "#OWNER#"."XXPAY_EMP" but it didn't work, where PHOTO is my blob column. Can you please explain further. Thanks

Comment: Got it to work, turns out you need:'<img src="' ||
APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC 
(
    p_item_name           => 'P3_PHOTO',
    p_v1                  => to_char(PERSON_ID),
    p_v2                  => null,
    p_content_disposition => 'inline'
) || '" height="75" width="75" />' EMPLOYEE_PHOTO where P3_PHOTO is the field on the form where you upload the image